# different results for segmentation.find_boundaries for different platforms

Tags: python, scipy

Win7, python 3.6.4, jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np

import skimage.segmentation as segmentation

source = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
])

contour = segmentation.find_boundaries(source, connectivity=1, mode='outer', background=0)

print(contour.astype(int))
```

result is:

```
[[0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]]
```

In my opinion, this is right result.

But I try to do the same with DevAzure and have very simple project:

https://dev.azure.com/vovkvv/_git/Test%20boundaries

You could check pipeline and see that result in this case is

```
[[0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]]
```

This is

platform linux -- Python 3.6.10, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1

I used

```
numpy==1.18.1
scipy==1.4.1
scikit-image==0.16.2
```

as requirements.

So, what is the appropriate version of scikit for linux?

Comment: Please can you paste all you code again without all those `<br />`? Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

So, it is a bug: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4558

I use

```
contour = segmentation.find_boundaries(source.astype(numpy.uint8), connectivity=1, mode='outer', background=0)
```

to omit it.